# Spring 4 Rest @Query annotation not working with security Principal

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

I have a simple (still a demo program at this point) Spring program (Spring Rest and Security) that works in a plain way. Through JpaRepository I can GET all (/option handled by findAll()), GET one (/option/1 handled by findOne(Long id)), PUT and POST.

My business model says that a logged-in user should see only the records they have rights to. So a findAll() should return maybe three records, a findOne(id) should return one or zero.

I believe I must tie these to the Principal object in an annotation.  I've tried a variety of schemes but haven't yet figured what Spring wants of me. For the findAll() I've tried this:

```
@Override
@Query("from Option o where o.id = 11")
public List<Option> findAll();
```

However, findAll() still returns many records.

Then I tried to tie my query to the Principal:

```
@Override
@Query("from Option o where o.id = ?#{ principal.id}")
public List<Option> findAll();
```

(I've also tried ?#{#principal.id} )

This fails in interesting ways.

- When it returns HTTP 500 I'm told that "principal" can't be found.
- Once I reconfigure my program I get a HTTP 404, meaning I'm asking something wrong.  But since I don't know how to dump the principal.id value (logging from an interface?) I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Here is how I expose a UserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class JwtUserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
```

Here is how I configure the principal in the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version> -->
    </dependency>
```

and in Java:

```
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

My questions are:

- Why doesn't the @Query("from Option o where o.id = 11") return only one record?
- How can I tell the attributes of "principal", so I can tell if its ID is what I think it is?
- Are there other questions I should be asking?

Thanks,
Jerome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't the @Query("from Option o where o.id = 11") return only one record?

Because this is not a valid JPQL-query. Your hardcoded test-query must be `@Query("SELECT o FROM Option o WHERE o.id = 11")`

> How can I tell the attributes of "principal", so I can tell if its ID is what I think it is?

Your must enable the Spring Security SpEL functions for queries.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    EvaluationContextExtension securityExtension() {
        return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }
}
```

It`s explained [here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions).

Now `?#{principal.id}` will work, if you have a custom `UserDetails`-Implementation with an `id`-field. For example:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

public class HapaUserDetails extends User { //User implements UserDetails

    private final long id;

    //constructor and getters
}
```

Comment: I added the SecurityEvaluationContextExtension bit.  My GET one (/option/1) is now working with principal!  Thank you also for showing me that I was using HQL, not SQL.  So question 2 is solved.  However, my GET many is still not working:  @Query("select o from Option o where o.id = ?#{principal.id}") returns many rows, as does ... where o.id = 11.

Comment: It's JPQL not SQL.
Maybe there is something wrong with your `option`-entities in database. Check if they really have distinct id's.

Comment: In my app the Option.id field is annotated (at)Id and (at)Column(name="id"). The Option class is annotated with (at)Entity and (at)Table(name="choice").  In MySQL the choice table has "id" (int) as auto_increment, with a PRIMARY KEY index.  Yes, the database uses a different table name than the Java class. (Stackoverflow has issues with my using the "at" symbol, thus the substitution.)

Comment: And does `auto_increment` really work? You said "returns many rows". Why don't you look what is in the rows (in this case the id of each row)? I use similar queries in my envionment and have no problems. Did you try to annonate the `id` field with `@GeneratedValue`? Did you set the right `id` in your `UserDetailsService` implementation?

Comment: Auto-increment is working.  I have a POST working from the test web page, and each time I send a POST /option the MySQL client table gains a new record with a new ID value.  I set an outrageous @Query on findAll() and still got back all rows. Spring is currently ignoring my annotation on findAll().

Comment: Which Repository-Interface do you use? If you use ´PagingAndSortingRepository´ you have to override the `findAll(Pageable pageable)`-method instead.

Comment: I'm using JpaRepository and its findAll().  But if I instead annotate findAll(Pageable) I get the results I seek.  I will investigate the three interfaces (including CrudRepository) to see what I really want here.  Thank you, this question is answered.