# Explain the SQL expression

Tags: sql, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, repository, hsqldb

I'm going through the [spring-security samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/java-configuration/data/src/main/java/example/SecurityMessageRepository.java) on GitHub and found a class, which is a repository itself, where we use a `@Query` annotation.

*Database used: HSQL*

I don't clearly understand the contents of the query, particularly what does **m** mean and this part `m.to_id = ?#{principal?.id }` as well. This symbol is being underlined with red line and the following message is shown: `Cannot resolve symbol 'm'`

Code:

```
/**
 * A repository that integrates with Spring Security for accessing {@link Message}s.
 */
@Repository
public interface SecurityMessageRepository extends MessageRepository {
    @Query("SELECT m FROM Message WHERE m.to_id = ?#{principal?.id }")
    List<Message> findAll();
}
```

Here's my `data.sql` file used to populate the initial data (taken from the example):

```
insert into user(id,email,password,firstName,lastName) values (0,'rob@example.com','password','Rob','Winch');
insert into user(id,email,password,firstName,lastName) values (1,'luke@example.com','password','Luke','Taylor');

insert into message(id,created,to_id,summary,text) values (100,'2023-01-05 10:00:00',0,'Hello Rob','This message is for Rob');
insert into message(id,created,to_id,summary,text) values (101,'2023-01-05 11:00:00',0,'How are you Rob?','This message is for Rob');
insert into message(id,created,to_id,summary,text) values (102,'2023-01-05 12:00:00',0,'Is this secure?','This message is for Rob');

insert into message(id,created,to_id,summary,text) values (110,'2023-01-05 10:00:00',1,'Hello Luke','This message is for Luke');
insert into message(id,created,to_id,summary,text) values (111,'2023-01-05 10:00:00',1,'Greetings Luke','This message is for Luke');
insert into message(id,created,to_id,summary,text) values (112,'2023-01-05 10:00:00',1,'Is this secure?','This message is for Luke');
```

Could you explain what does mean that SQL expression or provide a link to some article explaining this? (because I can't even figure out how to google it correctly to find the answer quickly).

Answer (score 0):

this SQL will work, m is not a column in your table so you can't select it.
* will get all columns. And m is used as an alias for Message, so it will be resolved with the m.to_id column.

> `SELECT * FROM Message m WHERE m.to_id = ?#{principal?.id }`

Comment: This SQL doesn't work. I wrote the query as you suggested, but the `*` is being underlined with the description "<expression> or DISTINCT expected, got '*'". If I replace the * symbol with `ALL` keyword, `Cannot resolve symbol 'ALL'` and `Cannot resolve symbol 'to_id' ` messages are shown.

Comment: Try this then,same result different syntax: SELECT m.id, m.created, m.to_id, m.summary, m.text FROM Message m WHERE m.to_id = ?#{principal?.id }

Comment: everything ok, except of `to_id` – `Cannot resolve symbol 'to_id' `

Comment: Can you run this test? SELECT m.id, m.created, m.to_id, m.summary, m.text FROM Message m WHERE m.to_id=0

Comment: there's another thread with more info on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704036/spring-4-rest-query-annotation-not-working-with-security-principal